# How would a super long object orbiting a black hole be affected by time dilation?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion, time-dilation

Assume there is a long enough rod orbiting a black hole.

[image: TopView]
[image: SideView]

Such that the time dilation occurring on the two ends of the rod is noticeably different.

So, for example, the end that's closer to the black hole moves at half the speed of the other end.

How would the rod orbit the black hole?

- Would each point of the rod move at its expected speed based on the distance from the black hole, until all points reach equal distance from the black hole? ([Not accurate but I think it gets the point across](https://streamable.com/03w2f2), [SideView](https://streamable.com/ecmymw))
- Would the rod break apart as it's rotating at different speeds?
- Would the rod appear to bend or stretch, the same way light bends around the black hole?
- Or would something entirely different happen?

Comment: The rod would not rotate as pictured even without any time dilation. So asking how the time dilation would affect the rotation of this rod is not meaningful. Voting to close.

Comment: There are _no_ rigid objects, _no_ solid objects on this distance scale.  A "rod", far from being rigid, or even floppy, would be more akin to faint wisp of rarefied gas.  You could neither obtain such a rod, nor push it!